# Delete everything after a certain character on each word using sed

Tags: linux, sed, pattern-matching

I want to create a script using `sed` to achieve the following:

This:

```
22/0,01     1/1,05      11/0,01      35/6,04      6/0,03      3/0,04
```

To:

```
22 1 11 35 6 3
```

I want to remove everything after "/" on each word.

Comment: sed 's/\/[,0-9]\{1,8\}//g'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove everything from `/` up to a space:

```
$ sed 's@/[^ ]*@@g' file
22     1      11      35      6      3
```

Note I am using `@` as delimiter to avoid having to escape the `/`.

Answer (score 0):

if the "everything after the `/` consists only of known characters, then this is rather easy:

```
sed -e 's|/[0-9,]*||g'
```